# Not getting the link in deeplinking

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I am implementing the deeplinking in my app.

I have enable the associated domain and has mark the domain entry.

Server has put the association file at the root level.

For example associated Domain is "abc.in" my app url schema is testSchema.

When user click on link https://abc.in/testLink.com my app is getting open , but in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url

  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
```

method I am getting url as testSchema://. What could be the reason. I should get the url as "https://abc.in/testLink.com"

Comment: no need to set app url schema, remove that.

Comment: Unless and until testSchema://... url is hit, your app won't open. https://abc.in/testLink.com is hitting testSchema://abc.in/testLink.com internally.

Comment: Enable the associated domain and mark the domain entry that is enough remove your testSchema settings from plist.

Comment: If i remove that. App is not getting launch.

Comment: what's wrong if you get testSchema:// instead of https://?